# Reformat p values in table (R)

Tags: r, reformat

Say I have this dataframe.

```
 df <- data.frame(c(1.00000, 0.45983, 0.00134, 0.0675), 
      c(0.00001, 0.00000000064992, 0.9847, 
      0.0000000000000000000000000000000023482), 
      c(0.3452, 0.00011217, 0.023825, 0.00000055825))
 names(df) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
```

These represent p values calculated elsewhere. In another script, I have the code below, which works very nicely to reformat p values as desired.

```
 library(ggpubr)
 stat_compare_means(ifelse(p < 2.e-16, paste("p = ", p.format), 
      ifelse(p < 1.e-4, sprintf("p = %2.1e", 
      as.numeric(..p.format..)), sprintf("p = %5.4f", 
      as.numeric(..p.format..))))
```

How could I apply these same reformatting conditions to the pre-calculated p values in `df`, please? Thank you.

Comment: what is `p.format`

Comment: Thanks for your question. Please see edit above. I hope that helps? Thanks again.

Comment: If you aree using it outside the `stat_compare_means`, then do it inside `mutate`, i.e. `df %>% mutate_all(list(~ ifelse(. < 2.e_16, paste("p = ", .), ifelse(....`. Not clear about the expected output though

Comment: Thanks a lot, @akrun - That's exactly what I hoped for. If you want to put this as an answer, I'll vote it up!

Comment: @akrun - May I ask you a quick follow-up question, please? How would you apply this to one column only, please? I tried `df$B %>% mutate_all(list(~ ifelse ...`, but that did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: For that just use `df %>% mutate(B = ifelse(B  < 2.e_16, paste("p = ", B), `